# Como crear una table desde C#?

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo una aplicación en C# el cual hice un boton, para crear un table en mi sqlexpress nueva

He visto algunos codigos pero no tengo idea donde los debo de declarar (me imagino que en mi boton "crear"), y el siguiente problema que veo es para darle un nombre a mi nueva tabla.

Comment: Hola Chirino, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has de mostrar lo que has intentado , con codigo y ejemplos y los errores o problemas que tienes que hacen que no funcione. Mira [ask]  y [mcve] para añadir informacion a la pregunta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Para crear una tabla en una base de datos local:

```
        using (var cl = new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\\MSSqlLocalDb;Database=NOMBREBBDD"))
        {
            cl.Open();
            using (var comm = cl.CreateCommand())
            {
                comm.CommandText = "create table foo(id int primary key, nombre text)";
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Te sugiero usar [Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/) para el acceso a base de datos de una forma moderna. Con Entity puedes manejar la creación y actualización de tu modelo de datos, y usar LINQ para hacer queries en la base de datos usando objetos en vez de armar queries en SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //Crea tabla con tres columnas
dt.Columns.Add("1", typeof(int32));
dt.Columns.Add("2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("3", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add(1,"hasan","amiri"); //Agrega contenido a la tabla
ds.Tables.Add(dt); //Agrega la tabla a un DataSet
```